# Using a struct as advanced enum type and attempting to access the properties by index

Tags: c#, struct, reflection

I followed this guide on making a more complicated enum type for my implementation.
http://www.huristic.co/blog/2018/1/30/c-advanced-enum-value-types

So far so good, however now I need to access the struct properties I have made ideally by index. A use case is if I get in a list of integers, I want to be able to provide a list of strings with the seasons in, e.g. {1,4,7} would get me {"Winter", "Spring", "Summer"} for example.

So in effect, using this example, I would like to be able to select Month where the index is 7 for example and get out the season of "Summer".

My first step was to get the names like so:

```
IEnumerable<string> names = typeof(Month).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
.Select(x => x.Name);
```

I then attempted to get the particular Month with:

```
foreach(string name in names) { 
  Month m = (Month) typeof(Month).GetType().GetProperties()
  .Single(info => info.Name == name)
  .GetValue(typeof(Month),null);
}
```

however this is going to cause me to iterate over the entire collection for every value I want to get.

Ultimately I think I'm headed in the wrong direction and would really appreciate a pointer. At the moment I'm trying to do this in a method in another class, but don't see why it couldn't be a getter in the struct itself, although that may be complicated given the binding attributes in use.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach if you still wanted to use `Enums` for the months would be to create an extension class:

```
public enum Month
{
    January = 1,
    February = 2,
    March = 3,
    April = 4,
    May = 5,
    June = 6,
    July = 7,
    August = 8,
    September = 9,
    October = 10,
    November = 11,
    December = 12
}

public static class MonthExtensions
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> _seasons = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        {1, "Spring" },
        {2, "Summer" },
        {3, "Autumn" },
        {4, "Winter" }
    };

    private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> _names = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        {1,  "January"},
        {2,  "February"},
        {3,  "March"},
        {4,  "April"},
        {5,  "May"},
        {6,  "June"},
        {7,  "July"},
        {8,  "August"},
        {9,  "September"},
        {10, "October"},
        {11, "November"},
        {12, "December"}
    };

    private static readonly Dictionary<int, int> _seasonMap = new Dictionary<int, int>
    {
        {1,  4},
        {2,  4},
        {3,  1},
        {4,  1},
        {5,  1},
        {6,  2},
        {7,  2},
        {8,  2},
        {9,  3},
        {10, 3},
        {11, 3},
        {12, 4}
    }; 

    public static string GetSeason(int monthIndex)
        => ((Month)monthIndex).Season();

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetSeasons(IEnumerable<int> monthIndexes)
        => monthIndexes.Select(i => GetSeason(i));

    public static string Season(this Month month)
        => _seasons[_seasonMap[Index(month)]];

    public static int Index(this Month month)
        => (int)month;

    public static string Name(this Month month)
        => _names[Index(month)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static dictionary to associate months with their index:

```
public sealed class Month
{
    private static Dictionary<short, Month> instances = new Dictionary<short, Month>();

    private static Month AddInstance(string name, short index, string season)
    {
        instances[index] = new Month(name, index, season);
        return instances[index];
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Month> GetByIndex(params short[] indices)
    {
        return indices.Select(i => instances[i]);
    }

    public static readonly Month January = AddInstance("January", 1, "Winter");
    public static readonly Month February = AddInstance("February", 2, "Winter");
    public static readonly Month March = AddInstance("March", 3, "Spring");
    // ...

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public short Index { get; private set; }
    public string Season { get; private set; }

    private Month(string name, short index, string season)
    {
        Name = name;
        Index = index;
        Season = season;
    }
}
```

Then use like:

```
Month.GetByIndex(1, 4, 7)
    .Select(month => month.Season); // { "Winter", "Spring", "Summer" }
```